# Looking Bar chart/plot with two data sets in csv and plot multiple input files into a single plot unsing matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have 22 csv files in a folder each contain two data (X - 1KGP and 10KGP) I need to bar plot them by the bin size (Y) with two diff colour and label them (1KGP and 10KGP) in the subplot using **python3 matplotlib** would be great!

Read csv files in a folder..
option 1. Bar plot for individaul file
option 2. Bar plot all the 22 input files in single file with file names as title for each plot

Also looking adjust font size of bin value on the X axis or disply them vertically, setting bar width and space between each bin option and diff colour for each data 1KGP, 10KGP.

Any help much appreicated.

eg:: File: chr1_af_dist.csv

```
bin,1KGP,10KGP
0.00000,2340,0
0.00020,6776,5123417
0.00050,1187285,1017450
0.00100,412548,427317
0.00200,307560,282596
0.00500,345883,245059
0.01000,195499,124372
0.02000,159633,95077
0.05000,151972,99691
0.10000,95742,73652
0.15000,54230,49854
0.20000,39192,35856
0.30000,55605,51551
0.40000,37945,38420
0.50000,27848,33375
0.60000,23181,25561
```

Tried the following for one file..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("af-dist-barplot/chr10_af_dist.csv")
df.head()
      bin      1kg     10kg
0  0.0000     2204        0
1  0.0002     7319  5507880
2  0.0005  1287207  1076945
3  0.0010   448083   453606
4  0.0020   338917   300737

df1 = df[['bin', '1kg', '10kg']]
df2 = df1.set_index('bin')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
df2.plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('chr10_af_dist', fontsize=12, color='black')
#plt.subtitle('chr10_af_dist', fontsize=12, color='black')
plt.xlabel("AF bin size")
plt.ylabel("No. Of variants")
plt.savefig('chr10_af_dist.png')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

looking plot like this as an example but all the files in the folder "af-dist-barplot/" to be plotted in single output..
[image]

**Try1:**

```
with header csv..
bin,1kg,10kg
0.00000,2340,0
0.00020,6776,5123417
0.00050,1187285,1017450
```

..

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

path = r'af_dist-barplot' ## folder
files = Path(path).glob('*.csv')

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f).assign(Source=f'S{i}') for i, f in enumerate(files)), ignore_index=True)
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['bin', 'Source'])
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfm, x='bin', y='value', hue='variable', col='Source', col_wrap=2, height=6, aspect=2)
```

Comment: `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['bin', 'Source'])` and `g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfm, x='bin', y='value', hue='variable', col='Source', col_wrap=2, height=6, aspect=2)`, where `'Source'` is from **Option 4** of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you for answering my query. I'm new to this. Am I following correct. how to generate the plot here? from pathlib import Path
`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`

`import seaborn as sns`
`path = r'af_dist-barplot'`
`files = Path(path).glob('*.csv')`

`df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f).assign(Source=f'S{i}') for i, f in enumerate(files)), ignore_index=True)`
`dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['bin', 'Source'])`
`g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfm, x='bin', y='value', hue='variable', col='Source', col_wrap=2, height=6, aspect=2)`